# Using .datepicker() twice

Tags: jquery

I have a form that uses jQuery's `datepicker()`. That works fine.

Now, I'm adding in inline editing capabilities for my users. However, the `datepicker()` isn't returning a value to the editable field.

The script:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       $("td[id^=rowDate]").click(function() {
           $(this).html('<input type="text" name="editStartDate" value="" class="editStartDate" />');
           $(".editStartDate").datepicker();       
       });
    });
</script>
```

I'm not sure if it matters, but I also call the `datepicker()` after this function to handle a separate task:

```
<script> $(".startDate, .endDate").datepicker(); </script>
```

I want the `datepicker()` to return a new value to `#editStartDate` What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clean approach:

```
$(function() {
   $("td[id^=rowDate]").click(function() {
        // if there is already an input-field in this TD, return...
        if($(this).find('input').length > 0)
            return;

        // else create new input-field-object
        $('<input type="text" name="editStartDate" />')
            .addClass('editStartDate') // add the corresponding class (not useful anymore, but for completeness)
            .appendTo(this) // append that to the TD
            .datepicker(); // run the datepicker
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! One last thing, how would I replace the existing text in the `td`? Instead of `prependTo` I tried `.html` but that did't work.

Comment: Nevermind, I just figured it out. I used `$(this).html('');` after the `if` statement.